# Creating relationships in SQL Server via C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create relationships (1:1 / 1:n) for sql server via C#? Is this a viable this method:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0360__ADO.net-Database/HandletablerelationshipC.htm

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create relationships on the database or on the in-memory DataSet?

Comment: SQL Server only supports 1:n relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SMO library to do this. See msdn for an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162566.aspx)